# how to write a script in statsD to insert metrics information in graphite

Tags: graphite, statsd

Can anyone please guide me about how to write scripts for statsD & see the metric in Graphite.
I am getting the graphs for the default scripts run by statsd to graphite i.e Cpu usage etc
but i dont know how to write my own script to monitor some service in graphite.
& can u guide me about what statsd client & server do??
Is this how we write new scripts to implement new services??

Answer (score 3):

You can first try to play by sending metrics with a command line like :
echo -n "mymetric:1|c" | nc -u statsdhost 8125